# Can I revert to the original play through after starting the second?

Tags: knights-of-pen-and-paper

Just beat the game on Steam and hit the '+' symbol next to the save file without thinking.  I'd like to go back to the original play-through and try to fight Mom.  Any way to get back to the original play-through?